# Setting flex items to 100% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning how to use flexbox by reading some tutorials.

This is an example I have done without using Flex. I am using typical `float:left` - see example: https://jsfiddle.net/arhj8wxg/4/

I have tried to convert this to flexbox (example below) which seems to work (did I do it right?). Also do I need to include `<div class="header"> .. </div>` in each section bar when using flexbox? How do I set each section/sidebar to be 100% height?

```css
.container {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: shrink;
  height: 500px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #0b84ff;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.header {
  background-color: #1e5fa0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  height: 50px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <p>
      Sidebar Text
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <section>
    <div class="header">
       <button>Input</button>
    </div>
    <p>
      <textarea>Input Text</textarea>
    </p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="header">
       <button>Output</button>
    </div>
    <p>
      <textarea>Output Text</textarea>
    </p>
  </section>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flex code is mostly fine. It does what you need. Just a few notes:

- Instead of `width: 150px`, use `flex: 0 0 150px`, or add `flex-shrink: 0`. This disables `flex-shrink`, so the item cannot shrink below 150px.
- *"How do I set each section/sidebar to be 100% height?"* When you create a flex container, two default settings are `flex-direction: row` and `align-items: stretch`. This means that flex items will automatically stretch to fill the height of the container, whatever it may be. I set it to 100vh for the demo.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #0b84ff;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.header {
  background-color: #1e5fa0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  height: 50px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: pink;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <p>Sidebar Text</p>
  </div>

  <section>
    <div class="header">
      <button>Input</button>
    </div>
    <p>
      <textarea>Input Text</textarea>
    </p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="header">
      <button>Output</button>
    </div>
    <p>
      <textarea>Output Text</textarea>
    </p>
  </section>

</div>
```